# TI arm compiler not aligning struct members

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I'm having this struct here (bool is an unsigned char)

```
typedef struct
{
     bool a;
     int b;
     int c;
 } test_t;
```

If I look at the memory of a variable using this type declared on stack I see that the aligned of member b is not correct and is not on 4 bytes boundary.

EDIT: This is caused by the inclusion of FreeRTOS_IP.h which includes a ported file for ti CCS pack_struct_start.h / pack_struct_end.h. The pack_struct_end.h file is not working correctly causing all remaining structs to stay packed.

Comment: the TI compiler is just an odd  version gcc. Replace it with recent arm-gcc . If tool does not work, change it

Comment: `is not on 4 bytes boundary` perhaps. `read b and c wrong` I don't believe you even for a second.

Comment: @Blindy It is not on 4 bytes boundary. I see that there's only 1 byte difference between the address of A and B. It reads b and c wrong on a specific scenario. The question is more how can I force it to align members to 4 bytes by default.

Comment: Please post a minimal code example which is having the problem. Preferably with minimal header file inclusions and TI/HW specific stuff. And add your specific observations and how you gather these.

Comment: Sounds like this is either a question for ti or a bug report for ti, what did ti say when you contacted them?   Need to go there first then if the answer doesnt make sense and you can provide an example then come here.

Comment: the construction of a struct and a union and bitfields are implementation defined, there is no reason to assume how a compiler constructs its structs, this is why you should never use them across compile domains.   it is perfectly valid for the tool to generate packed structures if you want to think of that way if you have specified a target that can do that.  now if the code in the same compile with the same structure definition generates the structure in one way but accesses it in another way that is a compiler bug.  If it does not match your assumption of how things work, that is on you.

Answer (score -2):

> Why the TI compiler packs my structure by default and then access the memory like they are not packed?

The compiler does what you tell it to do. In your case, you don't tell it very much, so the compiler does what others tell it to instead.

Specifically, your structure is probably in a header file that gets included in a random string of `#include`s in different files, but since you don't specify packing parameters (which by the way are `#pragma pack`, not the all-or-nothing gcc-specific attribute) it uses whatever leaked from the other header files you included.

Here's the lesson to learn from this: if you care at all, at any point, about the memory layout of your structure (ie, if you use it to lazily access memory from files or network data), **always specify a packing attribute on your structure**. No exceptions, ever. Also clean up after yourself (`#pragma pack(pop)`).

Comment: I'm not using GCC, the question states TI ARM compiler. I wish it was gcc but its not. The TI ARM compiler does not even support the pragma pack macro.

Comment: @Machinegon TI compiler is based on GCC AFAIK. As @0 suggested, you can almost painlessly switch to a mainstream arm-gcc.